# Query not updating database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

Morning,

I have an issue with some of my code...
Basically i am trying to update or insert into the database. the first if statement if for when adding a new product. the else should then update any existing products.

However when i run it, it is not updating the existing products in the database. It is however setting the items ready to be updated. Any ideas?

Many thanks...

```
using (aboDataDataContext dc = new aboDataDataContext())
            {
                foreach (abcProduct p in abcProducts)
                {

                    var match = (from t in dc.abcProducts
                                 where t.sku == p.productcode
                                 select t).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (match == null)
                    {

                        // Watch out here; there is some type conversion required for certain fields!
                        abcProduct prod = new abcProduct();

                        prod.sku = p.productcode;
                        prod.categoryId = dc.Categories.Single(c => c.Name == p.category).Id;
                        prod.title = p.name;
                        prod.brand = p.manufacturer;
                        prod.description = p.description;
                        prod.abcPrice = p.price;
                        prod.size = decimal.TryParse(p.size.Replace("cl", ""), out size) == true ? (int?)size : null;
                        prod.country = p.country;
                        prod.region = p.region;
                        prod.vintage = int.TryParse(p.vintage, out vintage) == true ? (int?)vintage : null;
                        prod.weight = Convert.ToDecimal("1.50");
                        prod.strength = p.strength;
                        prod.bottler = p.bottler;
                        prod.age = int.TryParse(p.age, out age) == true ? (int?)age : null;
                        prod.caskType = p.casktype;
                        prod.series = p.series;
                        prod.flavour = p.flavour;
                        if (p.freestock <= 0) { prod.stock = 0; } //check to see if stock is 0
                            else { prod.stock = p.freestock; }
                        prod.abcUpdated = false;
                        prod.stockUpdated = false;
                        prod.priceUpdated = false;
                        prod.pricePublished = false;
                        prod.stockPublished = false;
                        prod.imgPublished = false;
                        prod.prodPublished = false;
                        prod.lastUpdated = DateTime.Now;

                        // Add the new object to the abcProducts table (only in memory here)
                        dc.abcProducts.InsertOnSubmit(prod);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // update row
                        match.abcUpdated = true;
                        //Set if an item has been updated or not.
                        if (match.stock == p.freestock) { match.stockUpdated = false; }
                        else { match.stockUpdated = true; }
                        if (match.abcPrice == p.price) { match.priceUpdated = false; }
                        else { match.priceUpdated = true;}
                        match.sku = p.productcode;
                        match.categoryId = dc.Categories.Single(c => c.Name == p.category).Id;
                        match.title = p.name;
                        match.brand = p.manufacturer;
                        match.description = p.description;
                        match.stock = p.freestock;
                        match.abcPrice = p.price;
                        match.size = decimal.TryParse(p.size.Replace("cl", ""), out size) == true ? (int?)size : null;
                        match.weight = Convert.ToDecimal("1.50");
                        match.country = p.country;
                        match.region = p.region;
                        match.vintage = int.TryParse(p.vintage, out vintage) == true ? (int?)vintage : null;
                        match.strength = p.strength;
                        match.bottler = p.bottler;
                        match.age = int.TryParse(p.age, out age) == true ? (int?)age : null;
                        match.caskType = p.casktype;
                        match.series = p.series;
                        match.flavour = p.flavour;
                        if (p.freestock <= 0) { match.stock = 0; } //check to see if stock is 0
                            else { match.stock = p.freestock; }
                        match.abcUpdated = true;
                        match.pricePublished = false;
                        match.stockPublished = false;
                        match.imgPublished = false;
                        match.prodPublished = false;
                        match.lastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
                    }
                }

                // Finally, request Linq to perform the database updates.
                dc.SubmitChanges();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: are you saying that it is inserting the new rows, but not updating the existing one ?

Comment: @Habib.OSU yes that is correct. Basically only 1 item might needed updating like the price, or stock. However neither are updating but the values are being passed to the "match.stock" for example.

I just cant work out why its not updating as it should.

Comment: I have had this problem before too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is problem in your code, you are iterating through the product table and getting the values in the `match` variable. In the part of the if statement where match is not null, you are setting the object to the new values, but you are not calling the `dc.SubmitChanges();`, that object `match` is not getting stored any where in your code, and in the next iteration in the loop, it is being assigned the new values.

You need to call dc.SubmitChanges(); after update the match values.

```
foreach (abcProduct p in abcProducts)
                {

                    var match = (from t in dc.abcProducts
                                 where t.sku == p.productcode
                                 select t).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (match == null)
                    {
                       //insertion code commented out
                        dc.abcProducts.InsertOnSubmit(prod);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ///.... setting up all fields. 
                        match.stockPublished = false;
                        match.imgPublished = false;
                        match.prodPublished = false;
                        match.lastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
                        dc.SubmitChanges(); //Call this otherwise you will
                                            //loose the match values in the next iteration
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Testing now :) I thought it might be something like that, but thought i would double check for peace of mind

Answer (score 4):

The context is loosing track of the object when setting match.

At the bottom of the else statement insert

```
dc.abcProducts.Attach(match);
```

Comment: with this would i only need one dc.SubmitChanges(); still?

Comment: mmm, maybe that would be better to submit all at once, than one at a time.

Comment: Submitting it all at once is better for transactional purposes, because if an exception (say from a conversion) is thrown than nothing will be added to database.